# Edit user - ms access

Tags: ms-access

I have a Login system which connects to a table called Employees. I now require to make an edit user form that allows me to edit the username or password of the person logged in.

i have tried using

```
 Me.UserName = Nz(DLookup("Username", "Employees", "Username='" & TempVars("EmployeeType2") & "'"), "")

 Me.Password = Nz(DLookup("Password", "Employees", "Username='" & TempVars("EmployeeType2") & "'"), "")
```

But this does not allow the changes to be saved.

How would I make it so that this tempvar 9username and password) are editable in text format?

here is a the code of how my login works.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Private Sub ButtonLogin_Click()
 Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Employees", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.TxtUsername & "'"

If rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.LblWronguser.Visible = True
    Me.TxtUsername.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.LblWronguser.Visible = False

If rs!Password <> Nz(Me.Txtpassword, "") Then
    Me.LblWrongpass.Visible = True
    Me.Txtpassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.LblWrongpass.Visible = False

TempVars("EmployeeType") = rs!EmployeeType_ID.Value
TempVars("EmployeeType2") = rs!UserName.Value


DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the TempVars use below:

```
TempVars("EmployeeType") = Me.UserName.Value
TempVars("EmployeeType2") = Me.Password.Value
```

Comment: Tempvars can only store data, Not store objects

Comment: @MattH  The TempVars collection can store up to 255 TempVar objects. If you do not remove a TempVar object, it will remain in memory until you close the database. It is a good practice to remove TempVar object variables when you are finished using them  Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/tempvars-object-access

Comment: no it doesnt seem to work TempVars("EmployeeType2") = Me.UserName.Value should show the username but appears blank